# Image above carousel on Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

i'm working on a website based on this template 
http://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/modern-business/ but i can't put an image on the middle of the carousel, above the slides.

This is what i've done so far:

```
  <div style="position:absolute; top:50px;">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <img src="logo.png" class="img-responsive">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

The image stays on the far left of the carousel and it won't even stay like that in other resolutions, what can i do?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to add a position/style to your parent div.
When you're using the `container` class, the width of the div is set.

If you want to change the position of the logo in bootstrap, you'll have to play with the `col-size-offset` css class.
Knowing that bootstrap is a 12 column layout, to approximately center, you'll end up with something like :

```
<div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
        <img src="logo.png" class="img-responsive">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This means that what's inside your `col-md-4` div is offset from 4 columns. Which is what we want. Tere will be 4 columns on the left of the logo, 4 on the div of the logo (there you might need to do a bit more of centering) and 4 on the right because that's what's left.

For more info on the offset, see: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-offsetting